# How I Compile Resources into my Application and Access them?

Tags: delphi, resources, package

How can I make a single `executable` package that contains DLL and Image Resource Files?

Then how do I extract them from my Executable at Runtime?

Comment: Possible answers might range from "add them as resources" to "better use an installer generator" to "no you can't do that" depending on **why** you want to put the files into an executable and **what** you want to do with the files once they're inside the executable. So, what and why?

Comment: Because I'm going to use that file as a single downloadable file and it's not important that what will be happened next.

Comment: @Kermia, unless you do this for the sake of the exercise, what you do with the big EXE file makes all the difference in the world. Hint: if your EXE depends on the DLL's, storing them as resources in the same EXE will not work because you can't link to them unless you first extract them. If you do this for the sake of download size consider using an Installer.

Comment: @Cosmin, agreed. it is OK for regular resource files, but if the Application depends on the libraries it may fail to initialize, especially if you are loading the whole DLL at startup.

Comment: @Cosmin, i wanna make my own installer :)

Comment: @Kermia, well for that purpose it is OK then. If I remember there is a Delphi example called ExeMod (not written by me, you will have to Google it), this shows a way of how to create your own installer, search ExeMod.pas - It may be a crude way of doing it, but it works if I remember. Otherwise the approach you are doing I see no reason why not.

Comment: @Craig, @Kermia, if you want to write your own installer a good starting point is looking at how [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) works. It's Open Source written in Delphi! Might as well modify that to do what you need, rather then starting from scratch. Might even discover you don't need to write your own since that one's *so good*.

Comment: @Cosmic, thanks for the tip but I am already aware of Inno, of course Kermia may not be aware of it however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Option 1 using the IDE (Delphi 2007 or Higher):**

You can click the Project menu, then select Resources..., which you can load any file into. For your purpose this would be RC_DATA.

**Option 2 without the IDE**

If you do not have the above option, you will need to use the BRCC32 (Borland Resource Compiler) to create a .RES file from RC file, which you then link to your Application. To link Resource files without using the IDE, try the following:

Lets say for example we want to add a a couple of DLL files, and the name of the DLL files are MyLib1.dll and MyLib2.dll, to add this open Notepad, and type the following:

MYLIB1 RCDATA "..\MyLib1.dll"

MYLIB2 RCDATA "..\MyLib2.dll"

Make sure the ..\xxx.dll paths are correct, so obviously you need to edit that.

Now you need to save this as a .rc file, so File>Save As..(make sure the dropdown filter is All Files *.*) and name it MyResources.rc. Now you need to use the Resource Compiler to generate the Res file, using this console command:

BRCC32 MyResources.RC

You can write that command by using the Command Prompt, Start Menu > Run > cmd.exe, alternatively you can find the BRCC32.exe inside the bin folder of your Delphi setup and drag the MyResource.RC file onto.

This will create a Res file named MyResources.RES which you can include inside the Main Delphi form of your Application, like so:

```
{$R *.dfm}
{$R MyResources.res}
```

**you can extract the resources by using something like this:**

```
procedure ExtractResource(ResName: String; Filename: String);
var
  ResStream: TResourceStream;
begin
  ResStream:= TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, ResName, RT_RCDATA);
  try
    ResStream.Position:= 0;
    ResStream.SaveToFile(Filename);
  finally
    ResStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you ,And how can i add a new resource without using the IDE(writing a code) ?

Comment: if by code, you mean the second option I suggested then I will edit my first answer to show this way too.

Comment: I'm sorry, i can't understand this part : `using this console command:
BRCC32 MyResources.RC` where should i write this command?

Comment: you can just add MyResources.RC itself to the project, without manual compiling to .res

Comment: In Delphi 2007, there is no Resource item under the Project menu.

Answer (score 3):

What I've found out to be convenient, is to use a .zip container.

Then you'll have two implementations:

1. Append some .zip content to an existing .exe, and the .exe code will retrieve the .zip content on request;
2. Embed the .zip content as a resource, then extract on request each content.

Solution 1 will add the .zip content after compilation. Whereas 2 will add the .zip content at compilation. For a setup program, I think solution 1 makes sense to me. For a way of retrieving some needed files (libraries, and even bitmaps or text) which are linked to a particular exe release, solution 2 could be envisaged.

Using .zip as format make it easy to parse the content, and allow compression. Using a tool like TotalCommander, you can even read the .zip file content with Ctrl+PgDown over the .exe. Very convenient.

You'll find [in this link](http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=232#p232) how you implement solution 1, and [in this link](http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?id=48) (same page, but another post) how to use the `TZipRead.Create()` constructor to directly access to a .zip bundled as resource. You'll find in our repository how it works with working applications: e.g. how we embedded icons, textual content and graphviz + spell-checker libraries in the *SynProject* executable.

About performance, there is no difference between the two solutions, at least with our code. Both use memory mapped files to access the content, so it will be more or less identical: very fast.

Comment: +1 for "append the data to the exe". Better suited for an installer, and apparently that's what the OP is doing.

Comment: Finally ,I download it but now , when I'm going to use it i get these errors : `[DCC Error] SynZip.pas(1179): E1026 File not found: 'deflate.obj'` , `[DCC Error] SynZip.pas(1179): E1026 File not found: 'deflate.obj'`

Comment: Take a look at the source code repository: you'll be able to download all the needed .obj files from http://synopse.info/fossil/dir?ci=tip