# Is there any component like ExeMod?

Tags: delphi, exe

I've downloaded some samples about `ExeMod` but they don't work in the Delphi 2010 and i don't know is it compatible with Windows 7 or not. Is there any component like `ExeMod` but without problems?

**Edit**

I want to make a simple installer application.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but possible reasons include (1) not telling us what in the world `ExeMod` is (is it a component?), (2) stating without any evidence that it does not work in Delphi 2010, (3) stating that you cannot use a component (?) because you "don't know" if it is compatible with Windows 7 or not, and (4) spelling "Windows 7" incorrectly. (The last one is most likely the least important reason.)

Comment: @Andreas ExeMod? Google is your friend: it's just one unit which seems to append some compressed data, with a "magic" marker, at the end of an existing exe.

Comment: @A.Bouchez You can find it with Google, but it's pretty remote. A link in the Q would help. Since you clearly have a good link please can you edit the Q.

Comment: I told you about ExeMod earlier, I assumed you were using a Delphi version earlier than 2007 as you were asking how to link resources into your Application. Be careful when using Exemod as some AV might detect virus for it as it alters machine code at runtime. There is no updated Unicode release for it however.

Comment: This question could be better if you described your goal. What were you hoping to achieve with ExeMod? Ask how to do *that* in your question, and if there are other components or libraries that do it, you'll see them mentioned in the answers. But you'll also get suggestions for other ways to solve the problem that don't necessarily rely on a specific component and its capabilities. At the very least, tell what particular features of ExeMod you require.

Answer (score 3):

It just sounds like your previous question, [the 1st part of my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042222/how-i-compile-resources-into-my-application-and-access-them/6043045#6043045):

> Append some .zip content to an
>   existing .exe, and the .exe code will
>   retrieve the .zip content on request.

This is exactly what `ExeMod` unit does, in much complete manner (full .zip archive support).

Comment: Thank you , how can i find `SynZip`? would you give a clear example?

Comment: The latest version of the unit is available from our source code repository at http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=SynZip.pas (select the latest version, then click on the "Download" link at the top of the page, just above the first line of the source code). The example is available at http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=232#p232 and in the comments of the source code. Use  TZipWrite.Append just after  TZipWrite.Create to add the exe content before using  TZipWrite.AddStored/AddDeflated to add some content to as .zip entries.

Comment: @Kermia, Go to http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=SynZip.pas, choose anonymous login, type in the `password` shown on the screen. From there on do as Bouchez says: `(select the latest version, then click on the "Download" link at the top of the page`

Comment: @all Yes, everything is explained in http://synopse.info/fossil/wiki?name=Get+the+source

Comment: Finally ,I download it but now , when I'm going to use it i get these errors : `[DCC Error] SynZip.pas(1179): E1026 File not found: 'deflate.obj'` , `[DCC Error] SynZip.pas(1179): E1026 File not found: 'deflate.obj'`